# Best practice for returning dataframes in python class

Tags: python, pandas, class, attributes, return

I was wondering what the best approach was to handling pandas dataframes in a class was. I have a complicated set of classes that each manipulate and combine separate dataframes, but I was wondering if it were a better practice to return the dataframes from the functions, or to keep them as part of the class attributes.

The two examples below illustrate the example. Is it okay to not return the df, and access it only through the class (NoReturnDf.new_dataframe)? Or is this not a best practice?

```
class NoReturnDf:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def dataframe_operation(self, df):
        #do something to dataframe
        self.new_dataframe = df.copy()
        return 1 #on success
```

```
class ReturnDf:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def dataframe_operation(self, df):
        #do something to dataframe
        return df.copy()
```

Comment: Return or not, I imagine you should copy the dataframe before `do something to dataframe`.

Comment: It depends on what the purpose of `ReturnDf` is. The minimal example shown here doesn't justify the use of a class at all. Also, it may be preferable to return `None` on success and raise an exception if there is an error. (And Python has a proper Boolean type; don't use `1` when you really mean `True`.)